# TCP sending with Unity

Tags: android, networking, tcp, unity-game-engine, tcpclient

I am fairly new to Unity, but I have created an app which upon the click of a button sends a simple TCP message to a very simple TCP server console application. The code works perfectly when i run it on my PC, but when i build it for Android and test it through my phone the message does not reach the server. Am i doing it wrong? Is simple TCP interaction done differently with android? Here's my Unity code:

```
public Texture btnTexture;
public GUIStyle style;
TcpClient mySocket = new TcpClient();
public NetworkStream theStream;
public String Host = "my_ip_address";
public Int32 Port = 8888;
public bool sent = false;
StreamWriter theWriter;
StreamReader theReader;

void OnGUI()
{
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect ((Screen.width / 2) - Screen.width/4, (Screen.height / 2) - Screen.height/4, 
                              Screen.width/2, Screen.width/2), btnTexture)) 
    {
        if(!sent)
        {
            mySocket = new TcpClient(Host, Port);
            theStream = mySocket.GetStream();
            theWriter = new StreamWriter(theStream);
            theReader = new StreamReader(theStream);
            sent = true;
        }
        theWriter.Write("TCP Message" + " $");
        theWriter.Flush();
        //Application.LoadLevel ("Page1");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing from the date you posted, it might be too late to answer it. However, I was facing some kinds of familiar problem but with iOS. I hope this may be helpful for ones who will search for this afterward.

I suggest to dig into the library you're using to connect the TCP connection. For my problem, the cause is from the parsing library TCP libs is using. The parsing library is somehow things that iOS didn't have.